# Magento 2: Show multiple grids in a page without using UI components

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I have a specific requirement in Magento 2. I need to **show two grids on a single page using Block classes** (**`without using UI components`**).

I have created one of the grids successfully, but I am not abler to find a way to show the second grid.

Please help me if anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Edit:
Screenshot[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot for more understand.

Comment: @ChiragPatel, I have added the screenshot.

Comment: have you found any solution?